# Firebase push notification in angular 7 failed to register serviceworker

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Itv.png)

Am getting this error when trying to implement firebase push notification.

> "messaging.service.ts:54 Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."

this is my messaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { mergeMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {

  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
    private angularFireDB: AngularFireDatabase,
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {



    console.log("firebase.....");
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        console.log(_messaging,"messegiung");
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
         console.log(_messaging,"messegiung");
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
         console.log(_messaging,"messegiung");
      }
    )
  }

  /**
   * update token in firebase database
   * 
   * @param userId userId as a key 
   * @param token token as a value
   */
  updateToken(userId, token) {
    // we can change this function to request our backend service
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      () => {
        const data = {};
        data[userId] = token
        this.angularFireDB.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
      })
  }

  /**
   * request permission for notification from firebase cloud messaging
   * 
   * @param userId userId
   */
  requestPermission(userId) {
     console.log(userId,"userId");
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
         console.log(userId,"userId");
        console.log(token);
        this.updateToken(userId, token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   * hook method when new notification received in foreground
   */
  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code of your messaging.service.ts

Comment: its added can u check.

Comment: Did you allow push notification in web browser ?

Comment: No actual experience here, so I’m posting as an comment. Web Notification requires Service Worker, the error message is saying that the service worker script isn’t found (404). Have you followed steps in https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md particularly the part where additional asset have to be created (or at least copied from docs) named `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

Comment: yes i did .a popup came.